# In Swift, how can I see the string that Process() passes to the shell?

Tags: swift, windows, cmd

I am trying to use `Process()` to start a task in Swift, but I need to see what is being sent to the shell for debugging purposes.

I am trying to send the following command:

```
gswin64c.exe -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER -c "(input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

If I run the very same command in an environment that uses a UNIX shell (bash, zsh, etc.), it runs fine. In Windows using cmd.exe, however, it fails, giving the following error message:

```
Error: /undefined in ".
```

I suspect that Swift is inserting slashes as “escape” characters. Is there a way to see the string that Swift is sending to the shell?

Here is a sample:

```
import Foundation

let inputFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: "input.pdf")
let task = Process()

// In MacOS or Linux, obviously, we would use the appropriate path to 'gs'.
// Use gswin32c.exe if you have the 32-bit version of Ghostscript in Windows.
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: #"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c.exe"#)

// The following works when the shell is bash, zsh, or similar, but not with cmd
task.arguments = ["-q",
                  "-dNODISPLAY",
                  "-dNOSAFER",
                  "-c",
                  "\"(\(inputFile.path)) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit\""]

let stdout = Pipe()
let stderr = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = stdout
task.standardError = stderr

do {
    try task.run()
} catch {
    print(error)
    exit(1)
}

task.waitUntilExit()

extension String {
    init?(pipe: Pipe) {
        guard let data = try? pipe.fileHandleForReading.readToEnd() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self = result
    }
}

if let stdoutText = String(pipe: stdout) {
    print(stdoutText)
}

if let stderrText = String(pipe: stderr) {
    print(stderrText)
}
```

As a follow up, can the command be written in Swift so that it gets passed on to GhostScript correctly?

---

#### Follow up:

There does not appear to be a straightforward way to see what Swift sends to the shell.

However, I was able to solve my immediate problem. It seems that the sanitizer sending the code to the Windows command shell inserts slashes in front of the spaces. I was able to work around the issue by removing the quotation marks on either side of the PostScript instructions (it turns out they are not necessary), and placing each element in a separate member of the array:

```
task.arguments = [ "-q",
               "-dNODISPLAY",
               "-dNOSAFER",
               "-c",
               "(\(inputFile.path))",
               "(r)",
               "file",
               "runpdfbegin",
               "pdfpagecount",
               "=",
               "quit" ]
```

Or else, if you prefer to see the entire working example:

```
import Foundation

let inputFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: "input.pdf")
let task = Process()

// In MacOS or Linux, obviously, we would use the appropriate path to 'gs'.
// Use gswin32c.exe if you have the 32-bit version of Ghostscript in Windows.
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: #"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c.exe"#)

print(inputFile.path)

task.arguments = [ "-q",
                   "-dNODISPLAY",
                   "-dNOSAFER",
                   "-c",
                   "(\(inputFile.path))",
                   "(r)",
                   "file",
                   "runpdfbegin",
                   "pdfpagecount",
                   "=",
                   "quit" ]

let stdout = Pipe()
let stderr = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = stdout
task.standardError = stderr

do {
    try task.run()
} catch {
    print(error)
    exit(1)
}

task.waitUntilExit()

extension String {
    init?(pipe: Pipe) {
        guard let data = try? pipe.fileHandleForReading.readToEnd() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        self = result
    }
}

if let stdoutText = String(pipe: stdout) {
    print(stdoutText)
}

if let stderrText = String(pipe: stderr) {
    print(stderrText)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this can be executed on Windows?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson,  yes, just tested it on Swift 5.5 for Windows.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, to clarify, I tested both the Swift code (it executes and runs) and separately the Ghostscript command (it works fine if typed into the command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the code in [swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation), I think I found how it modifies your arguments for Windows under the hood.

In `Process.run`, it first constructs a `command: [String]` ([Line 495](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Process.swift#L495)):

```
    var command: [String] = [launchPath]
    if let arguments = self.arguments {
      command.append(contentsOf: arguments)
    }
```

In your case, it would be:

```
let command = [#"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c.exe"#, "-q",
              "-dNODISPLAY",
              "-dNOSAFER",
              "-c",
              "\"(\(inputFile.path)) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit\""]
```

Then after a whole bunch of code, it calls `quoteWindowsCommandLine` to create a command for the Windows shell ([Line 656](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Process.swift#L656)):

```
    try quoteWindowsCommandLine(command).withCString(encodedAs: UTF16.self) { wszCommandLine in
      try FileManager.default._fileSystemRepresentation(withPath: workingDirectory) { wszCurrentDirectory in
        try szEnvironment.withCString(encodedAs: UTF16.self) { wszEnvironment in
          if !CreateProcessW(nil, UnsafeMutablePointer<WCHAR>(mutating: wszCommandLine),
```

`quoteWindowsCommandLine` is declared [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Process.swift#L164) (I've removed the comments for brevity):

```
private func quoteWindowsCommandLine(_ commandLine: [String]) -> String {
    func quoteWindowsCommandArg(arg: String) -> String {
        if !arg.contains(where: {" \t\n\"".contains($0)}) {
            return arg
        }
        var quoted = "\""
        var unquoted = arg.unicodeScalars

        while !unquoted.isEmpty {
            guard let firstNonBackslash = unquoted.firstIndex(where: { $0 != "\\" }) else {
                let backslashCount = unquoted.count
                quoted.append(String(repeating: "\\", count: backslashCount * 2))
                break
            }
            let backslashCount = unquoted.distance(from: unquoted.startIndex, to: firstNonBackslash)
            if (unquoted[firstNonBackslash] == "\"") {
                quoted.append(String(repeating: "\\", count: backslashCount * 2 + 1))
                quoted.append(String(unquoted[firstNonBackslash]))
            } else {
                quoted.append(String(repeating: "\\", count: backslashCount))
                quoted.append(String(unquoted[firstNonBackslash]))
            }
            unquoted.removeFirst(backslashCount + 1)
        }
        quoted.append("\"")
        return quoted
    }
    return commandLine.map(quoteWindowsCommandArg).joined(separator: " ")
}
```

You can copy-paste this into a playground, and play around with it. It turns out that your string got turned into:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER -c "\"(/currentdir/input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit\""
```

Apparently the last argument doesn't need to be quoted on Windows. `quoteWindowsCommandLine` does the quoting for you already. If you just say:

```
let command = [#"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c.exe"#, "-q",
              "-dNODISPLAY",
              "-dNOSAFER",
              "-c",
              "(\(inputFile.path)) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"]
print(quoteWindowsCommandLine(command))
```

Not quoting the last argument seems to work on macOS too.

Another mistake is that you used `inputFile.path`, which always produces paths with `/` (see [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/url-path-on-windows/40459/8)). You should use the "file system representation" of the `URL`:

```
inputFile.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { pointer in
    task.arguments = ["-q",
                      "-dNODISPLAY",
                      "-dNOSAFER",
                      "-c",
                      "(\(String(cString: pointer!)) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"]
}
```

Then it seems to produce something that looks right:

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.56.1\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER -c "(/currentdir/input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

(I don't have a Windows machine)

Comment: Turns out, the solution was to get rid of the quotes, as you suggest, and make each word of the command a separate member of the array. Also, in Windows, inputFile.Path correctly transforms the path to the Windows form (e.g/, “C:\Users\nnnn\input.pdf”). Apparently, Swift still does something to the spaces, so each word needs to go into its own entry. As a work around, I just realized I could also input the PostScript commands as standard input. But sadly, there is no straightforward way to see what Swift is throwing at the command line, apparently.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex Really? `path` gives you the correct path separator? I initially thought so too, but  seeing the forward slash in your error message, I became suspicious and checked the source code, which said otherwise. I also found the swift forum post that I linked which also says it uses `/`. Perhaps the behaviour you are seeing is specific to your Swift version or something?

Comment: yes, when I print the contents of inputFile.path in Windows, I get the correct delimiters (the colon and backslash). In fact, using the C string (as per your example) confuses the shell, and somehow the backslashes get eliminated. It might be more robust to use standard input so as to avoid using the -c option on GhostScript.